# Automation get otp in email using testcafe

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, testcafe

Right now i need to automation register flow but after sent email address, one OTP will be sent to email, how can we get that OTP and input to field

Answer (score 0):

TestCafe is a browser automation and testing tool. TestCafe is not supposed to handle any actions outside the browser. The recommended flow in this case is to create a test user and disable two-factor authorization for testing purposes.